What am I doing wrong when overriding this DBT package macro using dispatch?
I am trying to reimplement a few macros from a DBT package called elementary in my own DBT project. One of the bugs I am trying to fix is that the package macro is trying to cast a boolean to a varchar, which Redshift doesn't allow. This is the macro code in the package:
Package macro:
{%- macro edr_cast_as_string(column) -%}
    cast({{ column }} as {{ elementary.edr_type_string() }})
{%- endmacro -%}

My macro:
{%- macro edr_cast_as_string(column) -%}
    {%if column.startswith('is_') or column.startswith('has_')%}
        cast(decode({{ column }},true,'true',false,'false') as {{ elementary.edr_type_string() }})
    {% else %}
        cast({{ column }} as {{ elementary.edr_type_string() }})
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro -%}

I created a file with my macro in my project's dbt/macros/ folder and it automatically overrides the package macro if the macro is called without a namespace prefix, eg: "edr_cast_as_string(column)". If the macro is called with the package's prefix, eg: "elementary.edr_cast_as_string" it doesn't call my macro. This is important because the package internally calls its macros with the namespace prefixed.
To resolve this i added a dispatch statement into my dbt_project.yml file as instructed in the docs :
name: "project_x"
version: "1.1.2"
config-version: 2

dispatch:
  - macro_namespace: elementary
    search_order: ['project_x', 'elementary']

To test if dispatch was working correctly, I created a sql file that calls the macro in both ways (with & w/o the prefix), and compiled it:
with example as (
  select {{ elementary.edr_cast_as_string('has_arg1') }} as result1, 
         {{ edr_cast_as_string('has_arg1') }} as result2
)

select * from example

which compiled to:
with example as (
  select cast(has_arg1 as varchar(4096)) as result1, 
         cast(decode(has_arg1,true,'true',false,'false') as varchar(4096)) as result2
)
select * from example

My understanding is that both calls should resolve to my macro, but I cannot get the call with the prefix to resolve correctly. I am starting to think that only macros that are manually dispatched with the statement:
{{ return(adapter.dispatch('edr_cast_as_string', 'elementary')(column)) }}

are able to be further dispatched following the dbt_project.yml config, but I am currently at a loss. Where am I going wrong here?
I am running this on DBT Cloud v1.7 against Redshift.
